# Image loaded from Firestore using Picasso keeps a lot of space blank

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, imageview, picasso

I am loading an image stored in the Firestore using Picasso. However, on the screen, the ImageView takes a much larger space as compared to the actual image. Here is the screen that I am getting, providing two images as I could not get the image in one single screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Here is the code:

```
val param5: LinearLayout.LayoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0F)
val popPresImage = ImageView(this@Medicine)
popPresImage.layoutParams = param5
val presUri = Uri.parse(p0.child(querykey).child("List").child(listkey).child("Download Url").getValue(String::class.java))

Picasso.get()
.load(presUri)
.into(popPresImage, object: Callback {
  override fun onSuccess() {                                                                          
    popProgress.visibility = View.GONE
  }

  override fun onError(
    e: Exception?
  ) {

  }

})

popsublayout.addView(popPresImage)
```

I feel that this has something to do with Image orientation. The problem occurs when I use an actual device for testing. The spacing is perfect if I use an Emulator.

Any help would be appreciated as I have lost the last 48 hours trying to find out what is happening

Comment: If you just take the URL from Firestore and hard-code that in your code for use in Picasso, do you get the same result? If so, the problem has nothing to do with Firestore and you can reduce the complexity and remove the tag. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yes the problem persists even in that case. Removing Firestore and Firebase from the tags

Comment: You are missing fit on the Picasso chain

Comment: i added a .fit() but after that the image simply fails to load

Comment: Finally I was not able to find a solution to the problem. Instead I have shifted to Glide from Picasso. Now the image is displaying properly. Do not know what happened with Picasso. Can any Picasso expert look into it? In any case I have spent 6 days on this.